# Getting 500 Internal Server Error when uploading Laravel project from Linux environment

Tags: laravel, deployment, server

I've been using Laravel for two years, and I've never had any issues deploying applications on shared hosts.

However, the last time I created a Laravel project in a Linux OS and uploaded it to a shared host, I had a very hard time fixing the 500 internal error issue. So, I cloned the project to a Windows PC, updated Composer, and then zipped the project and uploaded it to the shared host, and it worked just fine.

Now when I checked the difference, I noticed that the main difference was in the **league/flysystem** dependency - it updated from "version": "3.14.0" to "version": "3.15.1", and the require section was updated from this:

```
"require": {
    "league/mime-type-detection": "^1.0.0",
    "php": "^8.0.2"
},
```

to this:

```
"require": {
      "league/flysystem-local": "^3.0.0",   // ==> this part was added on composer update
      "league/mime-type-detection": "^1.0.0",
      "php": "^8.0.2"
 },
```

So could this be the main problem? Does anyone know what the issue might have been? Do you have any advice for developing Laravel on Linux environments before deploying?

I tried checking the errors log on the shared host
I changed the directories permissions
I make sure the PHP version is matching the requirements
I double checked all database connections/credentials

Comment: Does the shared host PHP version match, meaning, is their version at 8.0.2 or higher? ... 500 is a very general error code. Can you take a look to the webserver log for possible clues?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

A 500 Internal Server Error typically indicates that there is an issue with the server configuration or the server is unable to execute the requested script.

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve the issue:

Check your server logs: Look for any error messages in the server logs. On Linux, the logs are usually located at /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/nginx/error.log for Apache and Nginx servers respectively. The error message in the logs may give you a clue as to what is causing the issue.

Check file permissions: Ensure that the file permissions for your Laravel project files and directories are set correctly. The web server needs to be able to read and execute the files. You can use the chmod command to ensure that the permissions are set correctly.

Check PHP version: Ensure that the PHP version used on your server is compatible with the Laravel version you are using. Laravel requires PHP version 7.3 or higher. You can check the PHP version by running the command php -v.

Check PHP configuration: Ensure that the required PHP extensions are installed and enabled. Laravel requires extensions such as mbstring, json, and openssl. You can check the installed extensions by running the command php -m.

Clear cache: If you have made changes to your Laravel files, you may need to clear the cache. You can do this by running the command php artisan cache:clear.

Increase memory limit: If your Laravel project requires more memory than the default limit, you may need to increase the memory limit. You can do this by editing the php.ini file and increasing the memory limit value.

Hopefully, one of these steps will resolve the issue and allow you to successfully upload your Laravel project.